# twitter4j multiple queries

Tags: twitter, twitter4j

Is there any way to make query in twitter4j search for more that one keyword?

Like instead of making more queries in my program I can make one which does it all, so I will have only one big stream of tweets that I can read?

I guess it would be something to replace this:

```
Query query1 = new Query("SOME RANDOM TEXT1" );
Query query2 = new Query("SOME RANDOM TEXT2" );
Query query3 = new Query("SOME RANDOM TEXT3" );
Query query4 = new Query("SOME RANDOM TEXT4" );
...
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Create a FilterQuery object and then set the items to track

```
FilterQuery filterQuery = new FilterQuery();
```

Create an array of items to track

```
String[] itemsToTrack = {"python", "java", "php"};
```

Set the items to track using FilterQuerys' track method.

```
filterQuery.track(itemsToTrack);
```

Assuming you have already created Twitter/TwitterStream object, use the filter method to start streaming using the FilterQuery object just created.

```
twitterStream.filter(filterQuery);
```

Hope this helps.